# What does AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap do?

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-5

I was trying to update bootstrap from 4.6.0 to 5.1.3, and when I do so I  get the error message 'bootstrap 5.1.3' is not compatible with 'AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap 4.6.0 constraint: bootstrap (>= 4.5.9 && <= 4.6.1)'.

The latest version of AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap is 4.6.0 (released 2021-03-16).

What does AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap do and how can I replace it?

Answer (score 0):

First a bit of background.  The type `PreApplicationStartCode` is used to hookup bundles.  The type is used by convention, it is static and has a static method Start (no parameters).  It gets called by System.Web.Optimization.

So, AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap consists of a dll which contains a namespace which contains a type of `PreApplicationStartCode` which has a Start method which adds a `ScriptResourceDefinition` to the ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.

It can be replaced by adding a call in your Application_Start handler (or a method it calls, typically BundlesConfig.RegisterBundles) to

```cs
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("bootstrap",
            new ScriptResourceDefinition {
                Path = "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
                DebugPath = "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                CdnPath = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
                CdnSupportsSecureConnection = true,
                LoadSuccessExpression="window.jQuery.fn.carousel"
            });
```

And voila, the package AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap can be removed and there will be no problem updating bootstrap.